# Does ZK offer Touch Event Handling?

Tags: events, mobile, event-handling, touch, zk

I intend to optimize my ZK desktop application for tablet computer.
So that's why I want to know if ZK/ZK Mobile offers touch event handling? I mean just like Sencha touch or JQuery Mobile does. 
I googled a lot but couldn't find anything. Just want to be sure so that's why I ask here.

Answer (score 0):

We do the transfer from the mouse events into the touch events.
 - mousedown >> touch start
 - mousemove >> touch move
 - mouseup   >> touch end